# Using the csh tail by exception

Tags: csh, tail

Please can you help me, I am trying to strip some data from the end of a file, say file.oot.

I would like to use tail command, returning everything except the last n lines. I would like to limit this to a single line command as part of a csh script. Is there a way to do this with the tail command, if not is there another option?

Command to return the opposite of:

```
tail -10 file.oot > new_file.oot
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I was approaching this from the wrong direction (literally) and should be using head. Using the following code achieves my goal.

```
head -n -10 file.oot > new_file.oot
```